# Sox --multi-thread option: Split stereo wav file to 2 mono files Windows Line command

Tags: windows, command-line, sox

I've written a batch program in windows command-line to take a stereo wav file and split the right and left channel into separate FLAC files using sox v.14.4.0 audio program.  Like so..

```
for /r %%n in (*.wav) do (
 C:\sox\sox.exe %%n -c 1 %%n.left.flac remix 1
 C:\sox\sox.exe %%n -c 2 %%n.right.flac remix 2)
```

However, this takes a bit longer than I'd like. I looked into this more and it appears that I can use SOX_OPTS and the --multi-thread option along with --buffer in order to perform two sox operations at the same time.

The Sox documentation states this:

The SOX_OPTS environment variable can be used to provide alternative default values for SoX’s global options. For example:

```
SOX_OPTS="−−buffer 20000 −−play−rate−arg −hs −−temp /mnt/temp"
```

Note that the way to set environment variables varies from system to system. 
Here are some examples: MS-DOS/MS-Windows:

```
set SOX_OPTS=−V −−no-clobber −−buffer BYTES, −−input−buffer BYTES
```

Set the size in bytes of the buffers used for processing audio (default 8192).
−−buffer applies to input, effects, and output processing;
−−input−buffer applies only to input processing (for which it overrides −−buffer if both are given).
Be aware that large values for −−buffer will cause SoX to be become slow to respond to requests to terminate or to skip the current input file.

Two questions.

1. Is it possible to do split 1 input file to 2 output files simultaneously using --multi-thread as explained above or another way?
2. If so, how?  (note: I haven't been able to figure out the correct syntax to get SOX_OPTS from the documentation above to work on it's own never mind in a batch file)

Also: I've found some other stackoverflow questions similar to this but always using java, php, linux, etc. Unfortunately, I don't have any knowledge of those programs. Please be sympathetic of my programming ignorance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea without getting more familiar than I'd prefer with your SoX...

However, I'd try this:

As a test, use a single .wav file

```
for /r %%n in (justone.wav) do (
 START "Left" C:\sox\sox.exe %%n -c 1 %%n.left.flac remix 1
 START "Right" C:\sox\sox.exe %%n -c 2 %%n.right.flac remix 2)
```

And perhaps it'll run two instances simultaneously on a multi-processor machine. (Window title is "Left" or "Right")

Now - if this works, then try

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
for /r %%n in (*.wav) do CALL :runsox "%%n"
GOTO :eof

:runsox
CALL :wait
START "%~1.left" C:\sox\sox.exe %~1 -c 1 %~1.left.flac remix 1
CALL :wait
START "%~1.right" C:\sox\sox.exe %~1 -c 2 %~1.right.flac remix 2
GOTO :eof

:wait
FOR /f %%c IN ('tasklist^|find /i /c "sox.exe"') DO SET running=%%c
IF %running% GEQ 6 timeout /t 5 >nul&GOTO wait
GOTO :eof
```

What this will do is execute the `:runsox` procedure for each `.wav` encountered, passing the .wav` name.

The `runsox` procedure will call the `wait` procedure - which I'll come to. When the `WAIT` is finished, it'll put on the left sox, then wait again and put on the right, then return for the next filename until all's done. The `%~1` in the names means 'the first parameter given to this routine, minus any enclosing quotes` - and that's the filename (%%n) provided by the CALL.

the `wait` procedure finds out how many `SOX.EXE` instances are running by passing a list of tasks from `tasklist` through a `find` filter to find the string `sox.exe` `/i` means regardless of case and `/c` means output a count.

`Running` therefore acquires a count of the instances of `SOX` in progress. If that is greater than or equal to 6 (an arbitrary number - choose it to suit yourself. Best to leave one or two processors for other tasks, so 6 id good for an 8-processor machine) then a timeout of 5 seconds is executed and after 5 seconds the tasklist is examined again.
When there are fewer than 6 instances, the `wait` procedure exits and the next task is started.

So - the `WAIT` procedure waits until there are fewer than 6 SOX instances.

Change the 6 to suit your machinery and the 5 your aesthetics.

Edit: remove legacy closing-parenthesis

Comment: One thing I did have to correct though was removing the ")" after the remix 2